# install ubuntu 17.04 usind wubi with already downloaded ubuntu image file

Tags: system-installation, wubi, 17.04

I have already install ubuntu by downloading the wubi tool and the image of ubuntu which i want to install in later ubuntu versions like 12.04 and 14.04, by manually downloading the image and the tool side by side in the same folder and disconnect the internet and the installation goes in its right way.

From two days ago i trying to do this way with ubuntu 17.04 but it insist to download the ubuntu image from the internet, i have downloaded these files :-

- Wubi for Ubuntu 17.04 (rev 321)
- Wubi for Ubuntu 17.04 (rev 322)
- ubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386

and as usual i put them in the same folder and disconnected the internet but it needs to download the file live.

if anyone can help me doing what i used to do, or at least make the wubi tool download the ubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386 not the 64-bit version.

Comment: wubi is no longer supported, so please use another method to install Ubuntu. See the following links, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229766 and https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0

Answer (score 1):

From [Wubi Guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Can_I_force_Wubi_to_download_and_install_a_32_bit_version_of_Ubuntu.3F):

> [..] start Wubi from the command prompt with the "--32bit" argument.
>
> To modify arguments without using the command prompt, right-click
>   Wubi.exe and select "Create Shortcut". Then right-click the shortcut,
>   select Properties, and modify the Target line, for example:
>   `"C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Desktop\wubi.exe" --32bit`

"--32bit" argument still works, also for [Community supported Wubi versions](https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki). Same folder is not enough if different file names are defined for 32 bit ISO and 64 bit ISO  ( /casper/vmlinuz, /casper/vmlinuz.efi )